# Random effect distribution

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model

In the mixed linear model we have the assumption that the random effect has a normal distribution, but in the generalized linear mixed model does the random effect also have a normal distribution or does it follow the distribution of the response variable?

Comment: We often make the assumption that the random effect in a linear mixed model has a normal distribution (this isn't necessary to do). Similarly, in practice, it's common to make the assumption that the random effect in a generalized linear mixed model is normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two points regarding the choice of this distribution:

- Random effects are subject-specific coefficients, appearing in the linear predictor scale. And, the distribution of coefficient estimators is often normal (from both the maximum likelihood and Bayesian paradigm perspectives). Hence, from that viewpoint it is logical to assume a normal distribution for random effects.
- The second point has to do about computational convenience. Namely, to formulate the log-likelihood of mixed models you need to integrate the random effects out. Hence, it is convenient to assume a distribution for which the integral can be solved. In linear mixed models the conjugate distribution for the random effects is normal. But for other mixed models it is not. For example, for Binomial data the conjugate distribution would be a Beta distribution, and for Poisson data a Gamma distribution. Nonetheless, because of the first point mentioned above often we select normal even for GLMMs.